# Efficient way to create new table with the same rows, but each one repeated different number of times

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

Say I create this table and an array of values:

```
names = {'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'} ; values = {'1'; '2'; '3'; '4'};
originalTable = table(names, values, 'VariableNames', {'names', 'values'});

nRepeat = [10, 50, 100, 2] ;
```

I want to create a new table which will contain each row repeated the number of times of corresponding index of nRepeat, i.e. I would have the first row or the original table repeated 10 times, followed by the second row of the original table repeated 50 times, and so on...
In addition, I want to add a column to that new table with the index of the repetition.

What I did:

```
% Initialize newTable to allocate memory space
totalRepetitions = sum(nRepeat) ;

% Repeated first row of the original table the same number of times as the totalRepetitions that will happen, also adding the new column with the index of repetition
newTable = repmat([originalTable(1,:), array2table(1, 'VariableNames', {'idxRepetition'})], totalRepetitions , 1) ;

addedRows = 0 ;
for idxName = 1 : numel(originalTable.names)

    newTable(addedRows +1 : addedRows + nRepeat(idxName) , :) =...
        [repmat(originalTable(idxName ,:), nRepeat(idxName), 1), array2table( (1:1:nRepeat(idxName))', 'VariableNames', {'idxRepetition'}) ] ;

    addedRows = addedRows + nRepeat(idxName);
end
```

This works, but it becomes painfully slow for large tables.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use [repelem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) on the indexes:

```
indx = repelem((1:numel(nRepeat)),nRepeat);
idxrep = arrayfun(@(x) 1:1:x,nRepeat,'un',0)'
finalTable = [originalTable(indx, :), table([idxrep{:}]','VariableNames', {'idxRepetition'})];
```

*finalTable:*

```
162×3 table

names    values    idxRepetition
_____    ______    _____________

 'a'      '1'             1     
 'a'      '1'             2     
 'a'      '1'             3     
 'a'      '1'             4     
 'a'      '1'             5     
 'a'      '1'             6     
 'a'      '1'             7     
 'a'      '1'             8     
 'a'      '1'             9     
 'a'      '1'            10     
 'b'      '2'             1     
 'b'      '2'             2     
 'b'      '2'             3
```

Comment: Thank you. Both proposed solutions are almost 10 times faster than mine. But Florian's solution is faster and would prefer to avoid iterating over each column  to apply the repelem (the case I showed had only two columns, but in reality I'm working with more than 30).

Comment: @cinico See my edit. The code should now be faster than my previous and Florian's solutions, let me know.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I have accepted your answer instead, because indeed is now the fastest (~60% of the time Florian's solution takes) and cleanest. I would just suggest that you make it more generic (see if you agree with my Edit suggestions).

Comment: @cinico Nice one, I approved and improved the edit. It now only shows the fastest solution.

Answer (score 4):

How is this?

```
Irep = arrayfun(@(n) n*ones(1,nRepeat(n)), 1:length(nRepeat),'UniformOutput',false); 
Irep = [Irep{:}]';
Iidx = arrayfun(@(n) 1:nRepeat(n), 1:length(nRepeat),'UniformOutput',false); 
Iidx = [Iidx{:}]';
newTable = table(names(Irep),values(Irep), Iidx, 'VariableNames', {'names', 'values','idxRepetition'});
```

Outputs this:

```
newTable =

  162×3 table

    names    values    idxRepetition
    _____    ______    _____________

    'a'      '1'         1          
    'a'      '1'         2          
    'a'      '1'         3          
    'a'      '1'         4          
    'a'      '1'         5          
    'a'      '1'         6          
    'a'      '1'         7          
    'a'      '1'         8          
    'a'      '1'         9          
    'a'      '1'        10          
    'b'      '2'         1          
    'b'      '2'         2          
    'b'      '2'         3          
    'b'      '2'         4          
    'b'      '2'         5          
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Both proposed solutions are almost 10 times faster than mine. But yours is faster and seems more clean for a very large number of columns.